# How to Show/Hide navigation list in Angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, passport.js, angular4-httpclient

I'm working on Login authentication with MEAN stack. I'm using angular 4 in the front-end. I'm trying to implement show/hide navigation based on login. When the user login it must show the navigation-list but it doesn't show it and it doesn't give any error but it only shows Login button before and after login. Here below is my code can anyone please help me on this where I'm making mistake. For Back-End login authentication, I used passport.js and express session. I'm not using JWT tokens.

//navbar.component.html

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <ng-template *ngIf="isAuthenticated()"> <!-- Here I used [ngIf]="isAuthenticated()" as well still it doesn't work-->
                <li><a routerLink="/jobs">Jobs</a></li>
                <li><a routerLink="/users">Users</a></li>
                <li ><a routerLink="/register">Register a User</a></li>
              </ng-template>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <ng-template *ngIf="isAuthenticated()">
                <li><a (click)="onLogout()">Logout</a></li>
            </ng-template>
            <li *ngIf="!isAuthenticated()" routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

//navbar.component.ts

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, 
              private router: Router) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onLogout() {
    this.authService.logout()
      .subscribe(
        (res) => {
          if (res) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          }
        }
      );
  }
  isAuthenticated() {
    this.authService.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

//auth.service.ts

```
export class AuthService {
    url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/users'
    constructor(private router: Router,
                private http: HttpClient) {}
    signInWithEmailAndPassword (userDetails) {
        return this.http.post(this.url + '/login', userDetails, { observe: 'body', responseType: 'json'})
            .map(
                (response) => {
                    return response;
                }
            )
    }

    logout() {
        return this.http.get(this.url + '/logout')
            .map((response) => {return response})
    }

    isAuthenticated() {
        return this.http.get(this.url + '/is-logged-in')
            .map((response) => { return response })
    }
}
```

*********** Node.js BackEnd Code ***********

//server.js

```
const userRoute = require('./routes/user-route');
app.use('/api/users', userRoute);
```

//user.router.js

```
userRoute.get('/is-logged-in', authMiddleware.isUserLoggedIn, authMiddleware.isUserActive, user.isLoggedInUser)
```

//authMiddleware.js

```
const authMiddleware = {
isUserActive: (req, res, next) => {
        req.user.isActive === true ? next() : res.status(401).send({message: 'No User Found!'});
    },
    isUserLoggedIn: (req, res, next) => {
        console.log('imcalled from auth');
        req.isAuthenticated() ? next() : res.status(401).send({message: 'You must be LoggedIn'});
    }
}
```

//user.controller.js

```
const user = {
    isLoggedInUser: (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send(true);
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you see any call made to is-logged-in API in developer tools network tab? Also, it looks like isAuthenticated() method does not return anything (true/false)

Comment: No, I don't find any call made to it! Why is it not calling?

Comment: Your call to is-logged-in returns an observable that you need to subscribe to to get the value out of it, currently you are using it as if it was a boolean value. This does not work here because the call is asynchronous.

Comment: @Benedikt Instead of returning boolean value do I need to return Object from back-end?

Comment: isAuthenticated() {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
  }

Shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `async` pipe, found at https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe.

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks.

You can assign `isAuthenticated()` to a variable and apply `async` to it.

```
_isAuthenticated: Observable<any>
ngOnInit() {
  this._isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated();
}
isAuthenticated() {
  return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
}
```

And in the HTML, `*ngIf="_isAuthenticated | async"`. (Add `return` to isAuthenticated() as RRForUI and Chau Tran perceived).

Another solution is to add a boolean variable and subscribes to the observable (this solution is better because, as Benedikt Schmidt said, Angular calls the server only once):

```
_isAuthenticated: boolean;
ngOnInit() {
  this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(res => {
    this._isAuthenticated = res;
  });      
}
```

In this solution, the function `isAuthenticated()` is not necessary anymore and, in HTML, you use just `*ngIf="_isAuthenticated"`.

Finally, return `response.json()` at `auth.service.ts`.

```
...
.map((response) => { return response.json() })
```

Comment: It is also necessary to return the observable from the `isAuthenticated() ` function. Currently it just gets called but there is no return value from it

Comment: @Pedro As you said I used Async Pipe but it gives me an error as ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'true' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: Benedikt Schmidt is right. We need to return the observable. I'm going to edit my question, but the solution I found was assign the observable to a variable and call such variable in the HTML.

Comment: @Pedro still I find same the error on the console 
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'true' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: Instead of returning `response` you return `true`, could you check if such error would persist?

Comment: @Pedro It's the same error. It says InvalidPipeArgument I think we cannot boolean values to the pipe?

Comment: I perceived now, as RRForUI and Chau Tran said, `isAuthenticated()` was returning anything and I changed my response again.

Comment: The variable is probably the better way to do it. When you check for authentication onInit you are only calling the server once, while with the current implementation you are calling it three times already. Also change detection may be easier